# Reason for downvoting should always be clarified in order to help improve question

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, voting

*I suppose this may belong to meta but I am unable to post there, so please move it there if you have the permissions to do so*

I have been following this site for a few months and also asked a couple of questions over different periods of time.

I find it very helpful that people can exchange so many ideas, however, one feature I find regrettable is the fact that downvoting is often not entirely clear, especially if it is not supported by at least a comment about the reason for being downvoted.

(see, for example, [this question about career advancement in a family business](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/) - how do I know what I can improve there? How do I know what's wrong about it?)

The worst part of it is that when a question is downvoted, it has little chance to attract visibility and thus further help to be improved.

I feel there have been a large number of very legitimate questions that have been downvoted for unknown reasons; **how can anyone say for sure that those reasons themselves were not subjective?** Since the scope of this site is to actually be objective, I feel there should at least be a justification for why a question should be dropped from the visibility list.

With a clarification, the user asking the question, or other users, may at least have a chance to improve the text and bring it back to being on-topic, thus leaving some space to making the question more productive.

I believe this would result in a win-win situation and increase cooperation on the website instead of causing negative feelings.

Comment: discussed in depth in [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and in multiple similar meta questions

Comment: It wouldn't be unreasonable for downvotes to be accompanied by a "reason", but that isn't the way the community works.

Comment: @joeStrazzere - And it wouldnt work because I would keep getting flagged for my custom reason "Because the OP is a moron and did not bother to actually read the question"

Comment: @Chad - yes, I'm sure such comments would get flagged.

Comment: related: [What to do with unexplained downvotes](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/168)

Answer (score 4):

[This has been discussed many times before on MSO... well, MSE now, and it's as good as it's gonna get](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135).  There will be no mechanism to force people to explain a downvote, and thus, most people won't.  As to why, three main reasons:

1. People will type anything in a textbox to "get past it," so forcing people to comment on a downvote results in a lot of garbage.
2. 6 comments all saying "your post sucks" are not useful, and do more harm than good.
3. There's already a tooltip next to the downvote button.  Read it, as it covers the vast majority of downvotes.  Not like you're entitled to an explanation of a voter's vote anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I downvote most often because I think the answer is wrong.  Telling the poster that I think they are wrong is not helpful.  the downvotes do that on their own.

If an answer is wrong then the only way to suggest a fix is to suggest they delete their answer.  Since many of the answers are opinions and it is just my opinion that it is wrong I do not even want to suggest that and would have an issue with someone else suggesting it.

For this reason alone I think this is a suggestion that should not be implemented.

Comment: __Comments removed:__ let's keep comments focused on improving site content and not criticizing other users please.