# What to do with unexplained downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have been in stack-exchange for quite a few years, and have been about 10% users in quite a few sites. So I do understand the culture of the place.

Unfortunately, I have been observing recently that every post of mine has 1 downvote - no explanation in the comment. No relation between any questions or answers. Just plain simple "down vote". Question is WHY?

If people have a problem with question or answer, I am open to criticism. But If you down-vote, do explain what makes you frown upon that question or answer. Plain simple down votes without any reason is plain enmity than any criticism.

It is a very bad cultural in workplace which I rarely see in other stack-exchange site.

What can we do something about it?

Comment: There is nothing you *can* do. And you shouldn't worry about it. People are allowed to vote whichever way they want. If somebody is deliberately targeting your posts, the vote-reversal monitors will deal with it. Otherwise, just accept that you can never convince *everyone*.

Comment: do unexplained upvotes worry you?

Comment: Related: [Explain and downvote - Good Practice?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/explain-and-downvote-good-practice)

Comment: Three downvotes is hardly a trend and you're also leaving out that you got at least one upvote on each of those posts as well. It's a bit much to suspect that a site has a culture problem from just that. Additionally the two answers you posted were on questions that are clearly off-topic to site regulars, and when people vote to close they sometimes downvote those answers, even if the author might not be aware of the problematic nature of the question. The linked thread and the main meta are pretty clear that there's no expectation that one should explain their downvote.

Comment: @Kaz: Your comment deserves to be an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The downvote button has the following text: "Does not show any research; it is unclear or not useful".

Unless you hear otherwise, you should assume that is the reason for any downvote. That's the way the system is designed to work.

> What can we do something about it?

You can appeal to the site designers to change the way the site works.

Comment: _You can appeal to the site designers to change the way the site works._ do notice though that this has been done at the very least every other week for at least 5-6 years now and it's been denied every single time.

Comment: @Magisch - that's true.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your [reputation history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/143/dipan-mehta?tab=reputation), where I see you got three downvotes yesterday.  All three posts were posted yesterday, meaning they were on the front page, and the downvotes were spread out over several hours.  I suspect, therefore, that they come from more than one person in the normal course of browsing the site.

People don't have to explain their votes, and on some sites downvoters who self-identify find themselves the victims of retaliatory voting.  If you reread the post and can see something that could be clearer or otherwise improved and you edit to fix it, then you might say that the downvote did its job.  (And its caster might even undo it.)  If you don't see anything wrong -- if it seems complete, answers the question, isn't snarky or rude, etc -- then I find it's best to shrug off a single downvote.  Isolated downvotes happen to everybody and we can't always figure out why; it's just part of life on Stack Exchange.  Be much more concerned with *multiple* downvotes.  If you can't figure out what's wrong and nobody's commenting, you can try asking about the specific post on meta or in chat.