# Feature Request - Downvote comment required

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

It would be nice to know why a particular answer is downvoted, as it provides an insight into flawed thinking on my end or a measure of whether or not the answer is actually useful.

I propose that, when clicking down vote, a popup appears to enter a downvote reason. When displayed on the answer the downvote comment would not display a user id (so as to prevent "retaliation" from a user).

This popup would not allow for blank comments. I know that "constructive" commentary doesn't have to be required, but it would (to my mind) show that the downvote was "inexplicable", and therefore the question might still have merit, as no reasoning could be given as to why it's not a good answer.

Comment: This topic has been discussed [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) and [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting) and [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/proposal-require-anonymous-comment-with-downvotes). The answer is always that while we can encourage users to leave a comment, we cannot force users to explain their vote.

Comment: Not just "no" but hell no. It's -2 rep, no big deal. I don't have to explain why I vote in the regular world, I won't explain here either, unless I see fit. Think about this a moment. It's possible to have -10 on a question, but still get +4 reputation out of it (3 up, 13 down). That's how unimportant downvotes are. While it would be nice to know why you're downvoted, sometimes my reason is "At no point did you approach a rational thought...everyone is now dumber for having read it" because it's that stupid.  I'm not going to put that in a comment.

Comment: related: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601) at MSO and [What to do with unexplained downvotes](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4640/168)

Comment: If you mouseover the downvote button, you will get a tooltip that says, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". If the user hasn't posted an explicit comment, you can assume that to be the reason.

Comment: @MaskedMan I don't like to assume anything. I want explicit explanation in place of whatever I "feel" like they're trying to say. There is no way to understand what their intent was via vocal or body language cues.

Comment: @SliderBlackrose Well, suit yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Since an up vote is +10 and a down vote is -2, the system already allows for the fact that there will just be jerks.  In order for a person to do any real damage to your reputation, they'd have to be obsessively down-voting you.  If that happens, it trips an algorithm and alerts the staff and mods, then someone has some serious 'splainin to do, and the down-votes are reversed.  It is not a concern.